# How to debug objc runtime linking multiple instances of the same library

Tags: swift, dynamic-linking, dylib

I'm working on a Swift project which links agains *libSDL2*. I had to patch a few things in that library to fit my needs and thus it currently lives in the same directory as my project and is compiled and linked from there. When I run my application, I get a bunch of warning form:

```
objc[13894]: Class SDLApplication is implemented in both 
/opt/local/lib/libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib (0x10f116228) and 
/Users/<my-project>/Libraries/SDL-install/lib/libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib 
(0x10ef6d240). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

I do have a globally-installed instance of `libSDL2`  under `/opt/local`, installed via MacPorts and used by some applications also installed via MacPorts, so I can't remove that.

I tried looking at the libraries that the compiled binary links agains but could not find a reference to the instance installed in `/opt/local`.

```
$ otool -L .build/debug/TestLines
.build/debug/TestLines:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 1770.255.0)
    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1292.60.1)
    /Users/<my-project>/Libraries/SDL-install/lib/libSDL2_image-2.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 3.0.0, current version 3.3.0)
    /Users/<my-project>/Libraries/SDL-install/lib/libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 17.0.0, current version 17.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation (compatibility version 300.0.0, current version 1770.255.0)
    @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1200.2.41)
    <...>
```

How can I debug this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In the end it was easy to figure out. It turned out that the `libSDL2_image-2.0.0.dylib` was linked against the instance of `libSDL2` from `/opt/local`. To figure this out I simply had to follow the libraries linked by my binary and inspect those instead of just the main binary:

```
$ otool -L Libraries/SDL-install/lib/libSDL2_image-2.0.0.dylib   
Libraries/SDL-install/lib/libSDL2_image-2.0.0.dylib:
    /Users/<my-project>/Libraries/SDL-install/lib/libSDL2_image-2.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 3.0.0, current version 3.3.0)
    /opt/local/lib/libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1281.100.1)
    /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib (compatibility version 9.0.0, current version 9.1.0)
    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 52.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 1677.104.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics (compatibility version 64.0.0, current version 1355.22.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1069.24.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
```

(The root cause in this instance was that I had to pass `--sdl-prefix` in addition to `--prefix` to the `./configure` script from *SDL_image*)